# How should I escaping quotes and line breaks for Oracle SQLLoader (sqlldr) importing?

Tags: database, oracle, sql-loader, import

FIRST: Yes, I know about CONCATENATE and CONTINUEIF, but I might not be smart enough to understand the documentation. I don't "get" how they solve my problem. Thank you...

I am in the position of having to **create** a file for importing into an Oracle DB by way of sqlldr.

The columns are required to be delimited by "~" (Don't ask.) In creating the file file, I have a few concerns about the way sqlldr behaves in respect to Quotes and Newlines.

If a simple row is to contain the column values:

```
One, Hello~World I "Like" you, and Three
```

How should I output this to the file? My first guess is

```
One~"Hello~World I "Like" you"~Three
```

I imagine it would be easy to import with FIELDS TERMINATED BY "~" OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' specified in the CTL file. What I don't know how to handle are the quotes around the Like when I create the file. Should those be additionally escaped? How?

Additional Bonus Question:
The fields may contain line-brakes. If written out "raw" it would turn into

```
one~Line
Break~three
```

Is there an option in the CTL file that I can use to "stitch" these back together? The break may occur in different columns and there may be more than one break per record, or column.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some experimentation this is what I discovered:

While using

```
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "~" OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
```

in the CTL file and a table structure of

```
key:number, msg:varchar2
```

The right way to handle quotes and delimiters are

```
1~Hello World
2~"Hello~World"
3~"Hello ""World"""
4~"Hello~""World"""
```

So, If the data contains the delimiter, quote the whole value and replace quotes in the value with 2 quotes.

As far as newlines go, I am going to ask that in another question.